# when is echo after done in a while loop executed

Tags: bash, shell, echo, do-while

I came across the following simple time-returning script and wonder how and when the echo part can be triggered since it is placed after a while loop is done:

```
# !/ bin / bash while ! test -f / tmp / stop ; do date sleep 1 done echo " halted ! "
```

Comment: This code is completely broken. Please paste the actual script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `echo " halted ! "` is called after `done`, it is outside of the while loop. This means that "halted!" will only be echoed on the condition that we have broken out of the time-keeping loop, which would happen anytime the script goes back to the "top" of the loop, and checks if `test -f /tmp/stop` is true. If it is, the time-keeping stops, leading the script to the echo statement, and announcing the time-keeping has stopped (as we aren't in the loop anymore).